# Python try...except from the command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

How can I use `try...except` in a Python one-liner invoked from bash?

```
python3 -c "try: import foo\nexcept ModuleNotFoundError: print('no foo')"
```

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    try: import foo\nexcept ModuleNotFoundError: print('no foo')
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do it like this:

```
$ python -c "
> try:
>     import foo
> except ModuleNotFoundError:
>     print('no foo')
> "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
NameError: name 'ModuleNotFoundError' is not defined
```

Probably you should have used `ImportError` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out my question was a duplicate. Your solution works, but I ended up using `$'...\n...'` to interpret the newlines. Also, I'm using Python 3 which is why it raises `ModuleNotFoundError`. Sorry, I wasn't clear in my question.

Comment: @z0r I rolled back your edit since it fundamentally changed the code. The main problem is that `ModuleNotFoundError` is defined in Python 3, so it won't raise a `NameError`. I would normally say post your own answer instead, but the question's already been closed as a duplicate...

Comment: @wjandrea thank you very much!

Comment: @z0r good idea! Not working for me though: `python3 -c $'import numpy; try:\nprint(numpy.__version__)\nexcept:\npass;'`

Comment: @loretoparisi I think you still need to add consistent indentation after `:\n`. A single space would probably work.